# Strategy for VLOOKUP in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to fill a `Products` table in `file A` with their manufacturing costs that are in another `Costs` table in `file B`.

Currently, I read `Products` and `Costs` tables into their respective arrays and for each product I iterate over each cost looking for the right one. Basically, VLOOKUP done with arrays.

Isn't it `O(n^2)`? I feel like there should be a better way to do this. Should I use ADO? Dictionary with key as a lookup value?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use a dictionary. That will typically be cleaner **and** faster than anything else. Note, in VBA, you cannot directly put records of a user defined type into a dictionary, but if your `Costs` are just numbers, indexed by some product id, this is not a problem.